# OpenGL 4 software with ATI mobility radeon?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, opengl, ati-mobility-radeon

I am attempting a purchase of a laptop, that has ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 video card.

Usually, I only saw OpenGL being installed with Nvidia video cards drivers. I would like to know, if I can write and use my own software with OpenGl 4 library on a laptop with such a video card ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes;  AMD products support OpenGL.  The question of it supporting OpenGL 4 is an entirely different question and entirely dependent on the product itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [amd site](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-5700/pages/hd-5650-specs.aspx), no...
The card in the laptop supports up to version 3.2 and not version 4.

So you could however write your own software using OpenGl 3.2, or buy a laptop with a different video card which does support OpenGl 4.

Comment: The website you have provided says in the "1" footnote, that new drivers are scheduled to be released in 2010. And what about  [this website](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/b313/ati-mobility-radeon-hd-5650.html) , is it a reliable resource ?

Comment: The version of OpenGl or DirectX is hard coded in the card, software drivers will not change that. The website you refer too is not of AMD itself, so they could be wrong. Best is still to test it directly with a tool like GPU-Z. Moreover, OpenGl 4 was released march 2010. This card was released prior to that (january).

Comment: @JamesC - The mobile GPU in question does not support OpenGL 4